Issue in Kurtosis Based Polygon CDK Deployment on Ubuntu 22.04
I was trying to setup the Polygon CDK Private Environment using Kurtosis. I am facing the  error when I am trying to setup the enclave using the following command.
kurtosis run --enclave cdk-v1 --args-file params.yml --image-download always .

The excerpts of the error log is given below. Request your help.
Error: An error occurred running command 'run'
Caused by: An error occurred calling the run function for command 'run'
Caused by: An error occurred getting the enclave context for enclave 'cdk-v1'
Caused by: Unable to create new enclave with name 'cdk-v1'
Caused by: An error occurred creating an enclave with name 'cdk-v1'
Caused by: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = An error occurred creating new enclave with name 'cdk-v1'
Caused by: An error occurred creating new enclave with name 'cdk-v1' using api container image version '' and api container log level 'debug'
Caused by: An error occurred creating the logs collector with TCP port number '9713' and HTTP port number '9712'
Caused by: An error occurred creating the logs collector with TCP port number '9712' and HTTP port number '9713'
Caused by: An error occurred creating the logs collector using the '9713' TCP port number, the '9712' HTTP port number and the los collector container '&{}'
Caused by: An error occurred while waiting for the log container to become available
